# How can I get number of returned results from NSArray Controller in cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSArrayController named productsArrayController which is binded with an NSTableViev and returns records from core data. I want now programmatically to get the number of the records that are displayed in the NSTableView.

I know that I should do that from the data source (productsArrayController in my case) not from  the NSTableView, so I make an outlet from my NSArrayController. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *myArr = [_productsArrayController selectedObjects];
    NSUInteger total = [myArr count];
    NSLog(@"Total is: %ld",total);
}
```

Sure enough since I have no selected objects at this time, the above code returns 0, even that I have 9 records displayed in my NSTableView. Question is what should I use instead of selectedObjects to get the number of the records (9 in my case) here?

Comment: use `arrangedObjects` or bind an NSInteger property to keypath `arrangedObjects.@count`

Comment: arrangedObjects returns 0 as well...I can't understand why but....How can I bind property to keypath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` add

```
NSError *error; 
BOOL ok = [productsArrayController fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:&error]; 
int count = [[productsArrayController arrangedObjects] count];
```

Answer taken from the following thread [URL](http://idevapps.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=627)

Comment: I will test this solution in a minute....but...should I ask my data source on how many records I have?

Comment: Can you please clerify "I ask my data source on how many records I have?"

Comment: In my case, the productsArrayController is the data source for the nstable view...I just notice that I have error in my question, I am saying NSArray, instead of NSArrayController, i will edit that error now. So quesiton is how to get the number of records from the productsArrayController....

Comment: By the way, the code produces the error No visible interface for...declares the selector numberOfRowsInSections...I am working on cocoa app, I guess that that is the reason of the error.

Comment: how do you fetching the results by doing this : `[myAC fetch];` 
[I missed the cocoa app part , i was thinking about cocoa touch]

Comment: ok you can do one thing in applicationDidFinishLaunching: add `NSError *error;
    BOOL ok = [myAc fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:&error]; if( [[myAC arrangedObjects] count] == 0 )
{
[do some:thing];
}
`

Comment: Let me know if this works or not, if it works i will update the answer or i will delete the ans

Comment: Yeah, it works....the solution is: int total = [_productsArrayController arrangedObjects] count]; Please update your answer, so I can accept it. Thanks for the help